# Redirect output to filename specified by VAR

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In a windows batch file, I'm trying to redirect output into a filename specified by a variable. I must be missing something obvious, but I keep getting files created with my variable name for a filename. Whats the proper way to resolve this?

```
SET OUTFILE="%TEMP%\MyOutput.txt"

REM hopefully, create a MyOutput.txt file in the temp folder with "some text" as content
echo some text > %OUTFILE%
```

Comment: What do you get? It should work this way.

Comment: jeb beat me by seconds - it works on my machine. Does the exact code you posted fail on yours?

Comment: @Bali C - a permissions problem would not cause the file to be named OUTFILE. It would simply cause an error with no file created.

Comment: @dbenham Yeah your right, I didn't read the OP properly, thanks!

Comment: <facepalm> In my original file I had SET OUTFILE = "blah" and it did not work. I finally found that the problem was the space between OUTFILE and =. With the space in there, the batch interpreter does not expand the variable as I had expected. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

dbenham is right.

You cannot create the file in a location the way you have it, but you can get around this...

This will work, however, if you do the following:

```
SET OUTFILE=%TEMP%

REM hopefully, create a MyOutput.txt file in the temp folder with "some text" as content
echo some text > %OUTFILE%\MyOutput.txt
```

By just changing the fact that your text creates the file, instead of you trying to set the filename in the variable makes this work.